# combing json deserialization with validation spring/jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have created my own custom deserialziation class to use with spring/jackson. This works fine with requestbody annotation and submitting json via ajax.

I now want to add a @NotNull validation annotation to a field. Hwoever I either get the error :

```
An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be immediately after the model attribute argument in the controller method signature:
```

Or no binding at all is performed, depending on what combo of annotations I use.  I have no configured any validators, how would I do this ?  I don't want custom valdiation, just not null ?

What I want to do is this :

```
public @ResponseBody myDTO saveDTO(@Valid @RequestBody myDTO myDTO, BindingResult result, Model model){
```

However with that, nothing is bound, the dto fields are null.  Even though when I remove the validation annotations it works fine the fields are populated correctly).